# UICollectionView: Random Cell highlighted

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview with various cells. One can be selected at once and the selection state is stored inside my business logic. If a cell is selected the whole section get's reloaded to update the UI to highlight the currently selected cell.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    cell.setItemSelected(selected: selected)
    return cell
    }
```

My problem is that a random cell get's highlighted to for a short time.
I also implemented `prepareForReuse()` but without any effect.

What can cause this?

Thanks!

Here the requested additional code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let pendencyDeficiencyType = deficiencyTypes[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PendencyDetailCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PendencyDetailCell{
            cell.titleLabel.attributedText = StringUtils.hyphenedText(pendencyDeficiencyType.rawValue)
            cell.indexPath = indexPath
            cell.delegate = self

            let selected = pendencyDeficiencyType == pendencyItem?.pendencyDeficiencyType
            cell.setItemSelected(selected: selected)

            return cell
        }
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PendencyDetailCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    }

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    backgroundColor = Styling.cellDefaultColor
    titleLabel.textColor = .black
}

func setItemSelected(selected: Bool){
        layer.borderColor = selected ? Styling.heagPrimary.cgColor :  UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        backgroundColor = selected ? Styling.cellSelectedColor : Styling.cellDefaultColor
        titleLabel.textColor = selected ? .white : .black
    }
```

Comment: You need to share more (relevant) code

Comment: What's the code that was replaced by `...`? this is probably where the problem is hiding.

Comment: Edit your question to show your entire `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method, as well as your `prepareForReuse()` method. The devil is in the details.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: you need to handle the else case when the item is not selected as you know the reusable cells dequeued from the collectionview

Comment: prepareForReuse should be implement in your custom cell's class (`PendencyDetailCell `?)

Answer (score -1):

As an option you can implement two separate cells.. one for each state and use it depending on the flag.

OR

Try to use different ReuseIdentifiers depending on the flag.